# checkout Helper Url overload not working

Tags: magento-1.7, overrides, helper

I have a simple need to change all the cart URLs to force it to a store's cart.  I have set it up the same way as all the examples out there, but it's not the data, it the URL I'm trying to get to.  Here is what I have.

**The config.xml**

```
<helpers>
  <centralprocessing>
    <class>Wsu_Centralprocessing_Helper</class>
  </centralprocessing>
  <checkout>
    <rewrite>
        <url>Wsu_Centralprocessing_Helper_Url</url>
    </rewrite>
  </checkout>
</helpers>
```

And the helper file, app\code\local\Wsu\Centralprocessing\Helper\Url.php

```
class Wsu_Centralprocessing_Helper_Url extends Mage_Checkout_Helper_Url{
    /**
     * Retrieve shopping cart url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCartUrl(){
        $storeId = 1;//pick up from setting.. look to later but hard code now
        return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getUrl('checkout/cart');
        return $this->_getUrl('checkout/cart');//old function
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve checkout url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCheckoutUrl(){
        $storeId = 1;//pick up from setting.. look to later but hard code now
        return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getUrl('checkout/onepage');
        return $this->_getUrl('checkout/onepage');//old function
    }
}
```

As far as I see it, this should be working but it's not.  Any ideas why?
Thank you

**UPDATE**
As suggested in the post, if the class is being invoked directly i.e. new Mage_Checkout_Helper_Url or if another class is extending it is may fail.  So with that in mind a quick test of the only other spot that has the method  getCartUrl() which is what I need to get at.  The helper file Cart.php (app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Helper\Cart.php) does have that function in it.  It  extends Mage_Core_Helper_Url.  So I added the helper file in my module app\code\local\Wsu\Centralprocessing\Helper\Cart.php  with

```
class Wsu_Centralprocessing_Helper_Cart extends Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart{
    /**
     * Retrieve shopping cart url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCartUrl(){
        $storeId = 1;//pick up from setting.. look to latter but hard code now
        return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getUrl('checkout/cart');
        return $this->_getUrl('checkout/cart');
    }

}
```

and adjusted the config to match

```
<helpers>
  <centralprocessing>
    <class>Wsu_Centralprocessing_Helper</class>
  </centralprocessing>
  <checkout>
    <rewrite>
        <url>Wsu_Centralprocessing_Helper_Url</url>
        <cart>Wsu_Centralprocessing_Helper_Cart</cart>
    </rewrite>
  </checkout>
</helpers>
```

This didn't help, so that doesn't seem to be the path I need I believe.

Comment: Cache cleared? Anything in logs?

Comment: yes cache was cleared and no nothing logged, and I'm in debug mode too

Comment: Is your module under `Advanced \ Advanced` ?

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure what you mean by Advanced \ Advanced but, if you mean is it running and installed (system/advanced) yes, and everything else in the module is working at this time.  Only this new part is not working

Comment: what I think may be in play is that in the sidebar cart template, which is what I'm looking at for confirmation that it's working, uses $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') so I believe I am not coming at this in the right way?

Answer (score 2):

I'm on my phone so I can't search for you, but you need to determine if the class is being invoked directly i.e. `new Mage_Checkout_Helper_Url` or if another class is extending it. That's the only way this rewrite won't work.

Comment: well it should be.. I tracked it back to that class.  I was I did a board search and that was one of only a few places and the others didn't seem to have a match for those methods.  so your saying it looks right, and should be working

Comment: Hello, I have edited the question to reflect the idea of coming from the wrong class to overload.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Based on OP update:

For the assertion that your rewrite is or is not working, you need to ensure that you are instantiating the correct class. The following test should suffice:

```
ini_set('display_errors',true);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
umask(0);
Mage::app();

echo get_class(
    Mage::helper('checkout/url')
);
```

Output will be one of the following:

- Wsu_Centralprocessing_Helper_Cart
- Mage_Checkout_Helper_Url
- blank / error message

It looks like what you actually need to rewrite is the block class which is rendering the link so that you may pas in the correct store scope. However, I question the need for such a rewrite, as you should be able to pass in store params to the `Mage_Core_Model_Url` class.

Comment: please explane what you mean on "you should be able to pass in store params to the Mage_Core_Model_Url class" but as far as putting your sinpet in, I put in in the sidebar cart phtml and just get a 404 oddity even after I added die();.  It's aready Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); in the index so that is removed. but yeah so I guess it's "•blank / error message"

Comment: ok did ini_set('display_errors',true);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

echo get_class(
    Mage::helper('checkout/url')
);
die(); instead and it's Wsu_Centralprocessing_Helper_Url so I would think I was right the first time here on using the helper url.php file

Comment: even better, just to be sure I do `echo get_class(
    $this->helper('checkout/url')
);
die();`   and I still get Wsu_Centralprocessing_Helper_Url

Comment: Tell me more about "what I think may be in play is that in the sidebar cart template, which is what I'm looking at for confirmation that it's working, uses `$this->getUrl('checkout/cart')`"

Comment: the sidebar cart phtml uses uses $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')  to get the cart url.  Under the scope,  $this->helper('checkout/url') Wsu_Centralprocessing_Helper_Url so it didn't fit the thought I was having that maybe it was looking somewhere else for the method.  I was basicly thinking that maybe it was coming from Mage_Core_Helper_Url maybe or that I was not getting the overload to happen.. or.. well I was just working it out and throwing ideas out but that doesn't mean that though was right.

Comment: You need to find out what `$this` is and rewrite *that* (hint: it's a block).

Comment: Yeah I looked there first, but the Sidebar.php doesn't have getUrl .. but.. well I'm already ready extending that area, you thining I need to put the url there?

Comment: so adding the file, and the right config with this as the php sidebar, `class Wsu_Centralprocessing_Block_Cart_Sidebar extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar
{
    public function getUrl(){
  $storeId = 1;//pick up from setting.. look to latter but hard code now
  return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getUrl('checkout/cart');
    }
}
` fails.  no  error even with the die statement used before

Comment: I also tried to change getUrl to getCheckoutUrl in the hope that it's carry.  there is not cart url getter in the block scoope and why I was looking in the helper to start.

Comment: I have tried the block way & what happens is if I do this class `Wsu_Centralprocessing_Block_Cart_Sidebar extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar` as the class, & just add the method getMainStoreUrl() and change the getUrl in the .phtml file, then it works, but if I switch back to getUrl() in the sidebar.phtml & chane the method in the block rewrite, it freaks out with the getUrl().  So it only breaks if you use the getUrl, so is it that It's it can't overload that method?  Do I need to adjust the lines in the config `<blocks><checkout> <class>Mage_Checkout_Block</class></checkout> </blocks>`